# Filter out events order by time based on their value

Tags: c#, linq, gaps-and-islands

***Question has been edited. See comments***. Changes are in italic.

I have the following list of ordered (start/stop) events that are generated by *multiple physical device identified by an ID. For simplicity, only data for one device is shown*.

```
Date       Hour     ID Event           IsStart
18/10/2021 10:35:22 1  DeviceConnected  True
18/10/2021 10:20:10 1  DeviceConnected  True
18/10/2021 10:12:20 1  DeviceConnected  False
18/10/2021 10:12:19 1  DeviceConnected  False
18/10/2021 08:24:14 1  DeviceConnected  True
```

Over a given period of time, which is usually 24h, I can't have two or more consecutive starts or stops. I need to remove "duplicates".

In the example above, that would mean, after applying a filter using linq:

```
Date       Hour     ID Event           IsStart
18/10/2021 10:20:10 1  DeviceConnected  True
18/10/2021 10:12:19 1  DeviceConnected  False
18/10/2021 08:24:14 1  DeviceConnected  True
```

**A start should be followed by a stop or nothing, and the reverse.**

This is a typical Gaps-and-Islands problem, right? Let's add the Island number to the initial data set. Unless I'm wrong we should end with something like:

```
Date       Hour     ID Event           IsStart Island
18/10/2021 10:35:22 1  DeviceConnected  True    3
18/10/2021 10:20:10 1  DeviceConnected  True    3
18/10/2021 10:12:20 1  DeviceConnected  False   2
18/10/2021 10:12:19 1  DeviceConnected  False   2
18/10/2021 08:24:14 1  DeviceConnected  True    1
```

Can I do that with Linq? If so, I should be able to retain only the first record on the island.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this with out-of-the-box LINQ functions, but by writing a quick "lag" extension method you can then accomplish it with a single LINQ statement:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Lag<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TSource defaultLagValue,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector
    )
    {
        TSource lagValue = defaultLagValue;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(item, lagValue);
            lagValue = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then for the purpose of this answer, I'm creating a class to hold the data (which you should already have):

```cs
public class Event
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsStart { get; set; }
}
```

Then, here's how you would run it:

```cs
var data = new List<Event>();
data.Add(new Event { Date = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18, 10, 35, 22), Name = "DeviceConnected", IsStart = true  });
data.Add(new Event { Date = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18, 10, 20, 10), Name = "DeviceConnected", IsStart = true  });
data.Add(new Event { Date = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18, 10, 12, 20), Name = "DeviceConnected", IsStart = false });
data.Add(new Event { Date = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18, 10, 12, 19), Name = "DeviceConnected", IsStart = false });
data.Add(new Event { Date = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18,  8, 24, 14), Name = "DeviceConnected", IsStart = true  });

List<Event> filteredData = data
    .OrderBy(e => e.Date)
    .Lag(null, (e, lag) => new {
        Event = e,
        PreviousItem = lag,
    })
    .Where(x => x.PreviousItem == null || x.Event.IsStart != x.PreviousItem.IsStart)
    .Select(x => x.Event)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
    .ToList();
```

After that, `filteredData` should contain your expected output similar to this:

```
Date       Hour     Event           IsStart
18/10/2021 10:20:10 DeviceConnected True
18/10/2021 10:12:19 DeviceConnected False
18/10/2021 08:24:14 DeviceConnected True
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on using 2 OrderBy ?

Comment: This works. I forgot to say that I have multiple devices generating events (question has been edited). And I can't see what the correct Where clause should be in this case.

Comment: I solved my additional problem by grouping events by ID

Comment: The first order by is to get the items in the correct order so that the `Lag` function will show the previous item as the one that came before it based on the date.  The second order by is just because your sample output was sorted descending by date, so it may not actually be necessary if you don't need them in order like that.  If you were able to get it working using a `GroupBy` that's fine, but you could also just sort it based on the ID then date, then in the `Where` clause you can check against the ID of the previous item as well.